# Java: How to tell when JFrame or JDialog is moved?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, listener, jdialog

I have a `JDialog` inside of a `JFrame` and I want it to move with my `JFrame`. So when the user drags the window around, I want the `JDialog` to stay at the same position.

How can I tell when the user drags the `JFrame` or `JDialog` so that I can set the position of the other? Or is there another way to do so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a Component Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html). You would add the listener to the frame and then move the dialog when the `componentMoved` event is fired.

Comment: Ah, I've been looking in the wrong place. Will accept when I can.